# Regex Generate of Key Pattern like follow

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate for some activation Key like `5char-5char-5char-5char`

I show above pattern need to check at `6, 12, 18` position has `Dash(-)` and have total length is `23`. I'm new Here please any one help me to Generate RegEx in Javascript.

`/[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z0-9]{5}/`
Is it Okay Right Choice ?

Comment: What's the type of char? (word character, whitespace, etc.) and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Any character + Digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex works well by you can make it more elegant like following:

```
/^(?:[A-Za-z\d]{5}-){3}[A-Za-z\d]{5}$/
```

Comment: `/([A-Za-z\d]{5}-){2}[A-Za-z\d]{5}/`   You made mistake here. Please Update answer with `/([A-Za-z\d]{5}-){3}[A-Za-z\d]{5}/`. Range is not {2} should be {3}

Comment: With non-capturing group and position assertion: `^(?:[A-Za-z\d]{5}-){3}[A-Za-z\d]{5}$`

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK2lB5/1)

```
var data = "5char-5char-5char-5char";
if(data.match(/^(?:[a-z\d]{5}-){3}[a-z\d]{5}$/,"i"))
{
    console.log("Ok");
}
```

Don't forget to add `^` and `$`.

Comment: `\w` will match the underline too.

Comment: @Kasramvd Yes. Thank you for your comment post edited